# How to upgrade tensorflow in anaconda environment?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I am having TensorFlow version 2.0.0 in my anaconda environment.
I want to upgrade it to an upgraded version.
How can I do it?

Comment: `conda upgrade`

Comment: If you're on windows, see this SO post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840496/upgrade-tensorflow-on-windows

Comment: you can use ```pip install tensorflow --upgrade``` in your anaconda environment (activate it first). Normally you could do ```conda upgrade ...``` but for TF this does not work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install the most recent Tensorflow (here: 2.2) on Windows when conda does not yet support it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61357038/how-do-i-install-the-most-recent-tensorflow-here-2-2-on-windows-when-conda-do)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
conda update <package name>
```

or

```
conda install <package name>
```

Note: A second install equals an Override...

Specific to your case:

```
conda install -c conda-forge -n <environment> tensorflow==<wanted version>
```

Comment: Why Conda Forge channel? Mixing in **conda-forge**-sourced packages into an Anaconda base environment can be problematic.

Comment: That is correct, although it should not make that big a difference in this case. Honestly, I was just searching and copying out a command I recently used, so that's the explanation xD