# using a tensorflow model trained on google colab on my PC

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I am using colab to train a `tensorflow` model. I see that google colab installs the following version by default:

```
import tensorflow
tensorflow.__version__
2.6.0
...
[train model]
...

model.save('mymodel.h5')
```

However, when I download the model to my windows pc and try to load it with `tensorflow/keras`, I get an error

```
import keras
import tensorflow
model = keras.models.load_model(r"mymodel.h5")

    model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

After searching on the net, it appears this is due to the different `tensorflow` versions (colab vs. my PC).

```
tensorflow.__version__
Out[4]: '2.1.0'
```

The problem is that when I install `tensorflow` with `conda install tensorflow-gpu` this is the version I get. Even trying to force `conda install tensorflow-gpu==2.6` does not install anything.

What should I do?
Thanks!

Comment: You may uninstall the old version of TensorFlow first after that you could install the other version ( 2.6 )

Comment: Did you try with pip instead of conda? see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46840496/upgrade-tensorflow-on-windows

Comment: @abdou_dev thank but with which command? conda will install the old tf2 version anyway, right? and I need the cuda stuff that comes with the conda install...

Comment: Try this : `pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.6 --upgrade`

Comment: thanks @abdou_dev, I will try right now. But will this take into account a possible different CUDA version for 2.6?

Comment: As mentioned here, you need Cuda version 11.2 and CuDNN version 8.1 https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu

Comment: thanks. Installing via conda and the using the `pip --upgrade` trick gives a small error `ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tensorflow 2.5.0 requires grpcio~=1.34.0, but you have grpcio 1.41.0 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.5.0 requires tensorflow-estimator<2.6.0,>=2.5.0rc0, but you have tensorflow-estimator 2.6.0 which is incompatible.`

Comment: You should uninstall `tensorflow-estimator` and TensorFlow , all TensorFlow packages first.

Comment: yes, I started from a fresh environment actually

Comment: Make sure that there is no any installed Tensorflow package on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

hacky solution for now...

1. download tensorflow 2.1 + CUDA and CuDNN using `conda install tensorflow-gpu`
2. upgrade using `pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.6 --upgrade --force-reinstall`

The GPU does not work (likely because the CUDA versions are not the right ones) but at least I can run a tf 2.6 script using the CPU.